# Unable to mount cifs in redhat 6

Tags: active-directory, mount, cifs, fstab, openfiler

I am relatively new to Linux, and I am trying to mount a CIFS filesystem from an openfiler instance I have on my network in Red Hat. The openfiler instance is authenticating using AD.

I am able to connect using samba:

```
smbclient '\\10.25.214.26\cluster_storage.cluster.Cluster' -U [DOMAIN]+[USERNAME]
Enter DOMAIN+USERNAME's password:
Domain=[DOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.6]
smb: \>
```

When I attempt to mount on boot via fstab, I am told that the line is bad during startup.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=[DOMAIN]+[USERNAME], password=[my password], 
domain=[domain.edu] '\\10.25.214.26\cluster_storage.cluster.Cluster' /mnt/scratch
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be this... but try forward slashes "/" instead of back slashes "\" in your specification of the share location.

So //10.25.214.26/cluster_storage.cluster.Cluster

Update: As per the comments the below, the possible low hanging fruit of slashes was not it, but perhaps we are still dealing with a syntax issue. Take a look at the format provided here for various cases (including fstab syntax): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263

Comment: Unfortunately that did not appear to fix the problem :(

Comment: Can you post the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Oh wait, is the mount line you posted what you entered into fstab? Or is that simply your manual mounting that is or is not working? fstab has a different syntax.

Comment: This is the mount line I pasted into fstab. I figured that this was likely a syntax error -_. Would you mind informing me of the proper syntax?

Comment: Per your reference, I formatted my fstab entry in the following manner:

\\10.25.214.26\cluster_storage.cluster.Cluster /mnt/scratch cifs _netdev, username=[DOMAIN]+[USERNAME], password=[password], dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=500,gid=500 0 0


Unfortunately I am still presented with an error at start up that the first line in fstab (this entry) is incorrect.

Comment: I just successfully tested on a VM and mounted a Win folder. Try this syntax: //10.25.214.26/cluster_storage.cluster.Cluster /mnt/scratch cifs  _netdev,username=[USERNAME],password=[PASSWORD],dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=500,gid=500 0 0  :if this does not work verify your path for both the mount point and target location.

Comment: Oh and note that I used just username, I did not specify the domain.

Comment: Using that syntax resulted in drive discovery. I am now getting the mount(13) error, but I'm sure I can sort that out. Thanks so much for your help!